# Why is this my code producing a segmentation fault when there is only argc[1]?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, cs50, argv, argc

I'm taking a intro CS course (CS50x) and came across a slight problem.

Why is this C code producing a segmentation fault when there is only `argc[1]`?

It should print the statement. Why won't it print the error?

Thanks in advance!

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //HOUSEKEEPING
    //Get/Validate Key
    string key = argv[1];
    int finalKey = atoi(key) % 26;

    while (argc != 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)

            if (!isdigit(key[i]))
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }

            else
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }
            //...
```

Comment: You need to check if `argc == 2`, before accessing `argv[1]`.

Comment: Furthermore `while (argc != 2)` is nonsense, as `argc` doesn't change. You don't need a loop here

Comment: Please indent your program.

Comment: You do not pass the caesar-key. For a caesar-key of 1 (a --> b, b-->c, ...) you would run your program via `./caesar 1`.

Comment: What is `string` type? Is it `char *` and if yes - why you do not use `char *`?

Comment: @i486 it's CS50 BS. They use `typedef char* string` to make the students somewhat believe that there is a `string` type in C.

Comment: I've tried using argc == 2 and the same thing happens. And I used a if statement as well to no avail. Yea, the CS50 ide has a header file that makes the char * data type into string.

Comment: @AlSolomon you're doing the test too late. Don't access `argv[1]` unless you know that `argc >= 2`. See my first comment.

Comment: I tried declaring those variables after testing the condition, but now those variables have become local instead of global. I can no longer use them.

Comment: I will try to create a separate function so they will work. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Jabberwocky It is not very good idea because there is `string` class in C++. In addition, if students have "fear" from pointers, it is better to learn python or other language.

Comment: @i486 yes I know, but you should tell this the people reponsable of the [cs50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/) course

Answer (score 2):

`argc` is an integer argument that keeps track of the number of arguments in the command line, there is no `argc[1]`, there might be an `argv[1]` if you provide a second command line argument, otherwise trying to read from a non existing `argv[x]` amounts to [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3), and is the likely culprit of the segmentation fault you are experiencing.

In light of that information you'll notice that the `while` statement makes little sense, `argc` remains unchanged so the loop will either never execute, or will be infinite if `argc` is not `2` (and the program doesn't crash).

The `if-else` is also fishy, it will always print the message and return, if the character is a digit or is not a digit alike.

Notwithstanding the goal of the program, a syntactically correct code should look more like this:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        string key = argv[1];

        int finalKey = atoi(key) % 26; //*

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
        {
            if (!isdigit(key[i]))
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Wrong number of arguments, usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }
}
```

<sup>*</sup> Note that `atoi` is quite unsafe, consider using [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). And you can operate directly in `argv[1]` ***i.e.*** `int finalKey = atoi(argv[1]) % 26;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not clear about the operation of `argc` and `argv`. `argc` indicates the number of parameters passed to the main function. At least it will receive one argument (`argv[0]`, which will be the name of the compiled C code). In addition, it will receive all the parameters that you pass through the command line.

In summary, the correct way to do it would be:

```
if (argc >=2){
        string key = argv[1];
}
```

Otherwise, you will have a `segmentation fault` when you try to access the `argv[1]` value.